# How to fix linalgerror object is not iterable?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-science, statsmodels

This is My General Cross Validation function:

```
    """
    General model cross validation
    """
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
    tscv = method(n_splits=n_splits)
    dt={"Train RMSE":[],'CV RMSE':[], "AIC":[], "BIC":[]} 
    if 'exog' in model_params:
        exog = model_params['exog']
    for train_index, test_index in tqdm(tscv.split(df)):
        if 'exog' in model_params:
            X_train = exog.iloc[train_index]
            x_val = exog.iloc[test_index]
            model_params['exog'] = X_train
        else:
            X_train = None
            x_val = None
        train_fold = df.iloc[train_index]
        cv_fold = df.iloc[test_index]
        # if 'enforce_stationarity' in model_params:
        #     model_params['enforce_stationarity'] = True
        if 'use_exact_diffuse' in model_params:
            model_params['use_exact_diffuse'] = True

        forecast_model = model(train_fold, **model_params).fit()
        try:
            if X_train is not None:
                train_preds = forecast_model.predict(start=train_fold.index[0], end=train_fold.index[-1], exog=X_train)
            else:
                train_preds= forecast_model.predict(start=train_fold.index[0], end=train_fold.index[-1])
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass
        
        dt['Train RMSE'].append(mean_squared_error(train_fold[0:], train_preds,squared=False))
        if x_val is not None:
            test_preds = forecast_model.predict(start=cv_fold.index[0], end=cv_fold.index[-1], exog=x_val)
        else:
            test_preds = forecast_model.predict(start=cv_fold.index[0], end=cv_fold.index[-1])
        dt['CV RMSE'].append(mean_squared_error(cv_fold, test_preds,squared=False))
        dt['AIC'].append(forecast_model.aic)
        dt['BIC'].append(forecast_model.bic)
    if return_model:
        if 'exog' in model_params:
            model_params['exog'] = exog
        model_for_diagnostic = model(df, **model_params).fit()
        return pd.DataFrame(dt), model_for_diagnostic
    else:
        return pd.DataFrame(dt)
# To get summary info
def organize(df):
    cols = [pd.DataFrame(df[col]) for col in df.keys()]
    return pd.concat(cols, axis=1, keys=df.keys()).describe().T.drop(columns=['count', 'max' , '25%', '75%', '50%'])
```

This is my parallel helper function:

```
    """
    Helper function to return mean score of train and cv scores mainly for ARIMA related models
    """
    try:
        df = general_cv(model,df,model_params=param_grid)
        train_rmse,cv_rmse =df[['Train RMSE', 'CV RMSE']].describe().loc['mean']
        return train_rmse,cv_rmse
    except Exception as e:
        return e
```

This is my Gridsearch function:

```
    """
    Gridsearch for ARIMA/etc
    """
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
    joblib_parallel = joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=verbose)
    try:
        train_rmse, cv_rmse = tuple(zip(*joblib_parallel((joblib.delayed(parallel_helper)(df, param, model) for param in param_grid))))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    param_grid = np.array(param_grid)
    df_return = pd.DataFrame({
        "Train RMSE" : train_rmse,
        "CV RMSE" : cv_rmse,
        "Order" : [param['order'] if 'order' in param else np.nan for param in param_grid],
        "Seasonal Order" :  [param['seasonal_order'] if 'seasonal_order' in param else np.nan for param in param_grid],
        "Trend param" :  [param['trend'] if 'trend' in param else np.nan for param in param_grid],
        "Autoregressive" :  [param['autoregressive'] if 'autoregressive' in param else np.nan for param in param_grid],
        "Seasonal" :  [param['seasonal'] if 'seasonal' in param else np.nan for param in param_grid]
    })
    if sort:
        # display(df_return)
        return df_return.dropna(axis=1, thresh=.9).sort_values(by=['CV RMSE', 'Train RMSE'], na_position='last')
    else:
        return df_return.dropna(axis=1, thresh=0.9)
```

This is how I run my code:

```
sarimax_param=list(dict (
    order = (p, 0, q),
    seasonal_order = (P, 0, Q, 7),
    exog=exogfull)
        for p in range(3)
                for q in range(3)
                    for P in range(3)
                        for Q in range(3))
sarimax_results = defaultdict ()
for gas in tqdm(gases) :
    sarimax_results[gas] = GridSearch (df[gas], param_grid = sarimax_param, model=SARIMAX, verbose=0, sort=True)
```

This is the error I get when I run my code:

```
       'LinAlgError' object is not iterable

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\ASHER~1.LAP\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_25012/3656160125.py in <module>
     10 sarimax_results = defaultdict ()
     11 for gas in tqdm(gases) :
---> 12     sarimax_results[gas] = GridSearch (df[gas], param_grid = sarimax_param, model=SARIMAX, verbose=0, sort=True)

C:\Users\ASHER~1.LAP\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_25012/1404306223.py in GridSearch(df, param_grid, model, verbose, n_jobs, sort)
     11     param_grid = np.array(param_grid)
     12     df_return = pd.DataFrame({
---> 13         "Train RMSE" : train_rmse,
     14         "CV RMSE" : cv_rmse,
     15         "Order" : [param['order'] if 'order' in param else np.nan for param in param_grid],

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'train_rmse' referenced before assignment
```

Anyone know what I did wrong?
This is the data: [train.csv](https://github.com/MicroKryptx/TimeSeries)
data is named: train.csv

When I change the value in the range loop from 2 to anything higher than 2, it returns me this error. But when it is set at 2 it works for some reason.
Another thing is when I run the code separately for each gas as I pivoted the train.csv dataset earlier, the gas CO works but the other 3 returns the error.

Comment: You can't expect ppl to spend 15min in your question when you spent 30s to copy paste you code not in a synthetic way

Comment: you will have to show us minimal reproducible example, no one has the time to go over such a long post/code

Comment: what examples do u want to see?